# Placing HTML snippet inside of ASP variable issues

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a Classic ASP web page coded in VBScript. I have HTML code for a button that I only want to display if a certain variable is `True`. The issue that I am having is finding the proper syntax to place the HTML code inside of a variable because the button code itself has a snippet of VBScript in it that determines where the button link leads to.

Here is an example of my code and what I am trying to accomplish:

```
yesNo= False
button= "<div class="view">
              <a href="<%=theImaFir4%>">  <!--The ASP here determines the link and is absolutely necessary-->
                   <button class="btn"type="button">View</button>
              </a>
        </div>"
```

This is along the lines of what I want:

```
If Not theImaFir4="#" Then 'default value of link is #'
yesNo= True

If yesNo= True Then
Response.write(button)
```

Any ideas on how to properly place my HTML and ASP code inside of my button variable? Doing it the way I have done, the `%>` tag in the HTML snippet closes out the rest of my ASP code.

I have done my best to explain what I am trying to accomplish but if you require any more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make life easier on yourself and use single quotes for HTML attribute values. Then you don't have to worry about the need to escape double-quotes in VBScript.

Also, VBScript interprets the end-of-line marker as the end of a statement so you can't continue your string assignment across multiple lines without using the line-continuation (`_`) and concatenation (`&`) operators.

For example:

```
button = "<div class='view'>" _
         & "<a href='" & theImaFir4 & "'>" _
         & "<button class='btn' type='button'>View</button>" _
         & "</a>" _
         & "</div>"
```

There's also no need for `<%= %>` here since you're already in an ASP code tag if you're writing VBScript. Just concatenate your variable into your string:

```
"<a href='" & theImaFir4 & "'>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to open a new asp tag.  You also need to make sure to escape the double quotes inside the button's text.

```
button= "<div class=""view"">
          <a href=""" & theImaFir4 & """>  
               <button class=""btn"" type=""button"">View</button>
          </a>
    </div>"
```

Comment: Updated my answer because VB uses "" to escape double quotes as opposed to what I previously had which was \"

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other answers I would also add that using `<%=theImaFir4%>` is only for inline html use, because it triggers a `Response.Write` event.

When you are already inside the brackets `<%` `%>` you don't use the equal sign to display html because you are not there yet.  But you can use `<%=button%>` in your html however.

Comment: Thanks for your input, great advice!